# MySQL function doesn't work with unicode strings

Tags: mysql, unicode, utf-8, triggers

I have a MySQL function which does some string replacement in a specified string. I simplyfied this function to return it's argument.

```
CREATE FUNCTION replace_details(
    id INT UNSIGNED,
    message VARCHAR(1000))
    RETURNS VARCHAR(1000) LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
    RETURN message;
END;
;;
```

This function is called from `before insert` trigger, so the inserted string is modified. Everything works as expected while I'm using english text, but as soon as I'm trying to insert something else (for example russian) it makes my string unreadable. Actually I get only `?` sign in a database. If I'm using any other function in trigger it works fine

For example:

```
SET NEW.message = CONCAT(NEW.message, ' test');
```

but as soon as I'm using my custom function which actually does nothing, but returns what it got, inserted string becomes unreadable.
I guess I need to somehow specify that my function works with unicode, but how?

`MySQL server version: 5.7.1-m11`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it.

```
CREATE FUNCTION replace_details(
    id INT UNSIGNED,
    message VARCHAR(1000) CHARACTER SET UTF8)
    RETURNS VARCHAR(1000) CHARACTER SET UTF8 LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
    RETURN message;
END;
;;
```

works!